# Can't see a variable from a controller on a view - Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

My name is Carlos, I'm writing and I'm new on Rails 6.

I'm working on my app trying to show a variable, got from a form, on a view but I can't see it.

I'm using form_with sending the params(without model) to an URL of a Controller.

**Form on Meteo View (app\views\meteo\form.html.erb):**

Sending the params ":condition_met" to "briefing show controller URL":

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <%= form_with url: briefing_show_path, id: "met" do |fo| %>
        <div class="field">
           <%= fo.label "Condición Actual" %><br>     
           <%= fo.text_area(:condition_met) %>
        </div>
           <%= fo.submit "Enviar" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Briefing Controller (app\controllers\briefing_controller.rb):**

Trying to save the value of "[:condition_met]" on "@condition_met":

```
def show
  if params.has_key?(:condition_met)
     @condition_met = params[:condition_met]
  end
end
```

**Briefing show view (app\views\briefing\show.html.erb):**

Trying to show the value of "[:condition_met]" on the view:

```
<div>
 <%= "#{@condition_met} " %>
</div>
```

**The console actually shows that the Hash was sent to the URL when I click on the submit button:**

```
Started POST "/briefing/show" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-22 10:24:42 -0300
Processing by B**riefingController#show** as JS
  **Parameters: {"condition_met"=>"Test"**, "commit"=>"Enviar"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/briefing_controller.rb:4:in `show'
  Rendering briefing/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered briefing/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 211)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered partials/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 5906)
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 64.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 25974)
```

Nothing is shown on the view whith: <%= "#{@condition_met} " %>.

I tried some solutions on the web but nothing worked.

Regards!

**UPADTE:**

This is my route.rb:

```
  get "meteo", to:"meteo#show"
  get "meteo/form", to:"meteo#form"
  post "meteo/form", to:"meteo#form"

  get 'briefing/index'
  get 'briefing/show'
  post "briefing/show", to:"briefing#show"
```

I used the browser inspector and I saw that when the POST is made the inspector shows the variable in the answer but when I go to the view page it's not shown:

[image: POST]

If I use <%= @condition_met.inspect %> I get "nil"

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the question so well despite being a new contributor.

Comment: Can you show us your routes file, because `show` is by default a `GET` member route.

Comment: That's processed as a "JS" action. Check how you're rendering the request response (shouldn't that action be handled by a js.erb file?).

Comment: You can omit the check `params.has_key?(:condition_met)` as the effect without is basically the same (`@condition_met` not set and evaluating to `nil` vs. `@condition_met` explicitly set to `nil`).

Comment: Thank you very much @RajdeepSingh ! I updated the question and I added the route.rb file

Comment: @CarlosVergara Just answered your question, please try.

Comment: Thank you very much @RajdeepSingh ! It worked, now I can see it, but when I refresh the page the data is deleted. Do you know any way to maintain the data after the next submmit whithout using a Model and DB?

Regards!

Comment: @CarlosVergara It's because it's not in `params` anymore, the first time you submitted it, it was a post request, then on refresh it's a get request with no data in params.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh so there is no way to maintain the data, right?

Comment: @CarlosVergara Only if you are saving that data somewhere in the database

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help @RajdeepSingh !

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form_with` is by default `ajax` request that you are not handling in `show` action, add `local: true` to solve the issue

```
<%= form_with url: briefing_show_path, local: true, id: 'met' do |fo| %>
```

Give it a try.